# What is the correct way to activate a Server 2012 Guest in Hyper-V (NOT R2) with a server 2012 host using virtualization rights?

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012, hyper-v, licensing

I've done quiet a bit of searching on this and can't seem to find an answer, everything seems to refer to R2 and AVMA or just simply states you are allowed 2 visualization rights and nothing else.

Our company has a MAK license for Server 2012 Standard (NOT R2) - From what I've read, both 2012 and 2012 R2 allow for 2 virtual instances per license. I've found that you can activate 2012 R2 guests using the AVMA key but this does not work on Server 2012 only R2.

I don't want to just activate the guests with the MAK key as that will count towards an activation, unless this is the way to do it with 2012?

This technet question's first answer seems to imply that you activate using the MAK license then cry to microsoft later once you reach your activation limit. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ca3c084a-3ba9-4f60-a7c0-ef9b8d5206e2/licensing-windows-server-2012-in-virtual-machines-on-non-server-2012-host?forum=winserver8gen

Thanks in advance for the help!

--Edit--
Just to be clear, the host is Server 2012 with Hyper-v role.

Answer (score 1):

Server licensing is all about the physical hardware of the server and purely for auditing purposes. The product key you receive will be used to MAK activate the physical Windows Server 2012 standard server and also for activating up to two Server 2012 standard VMs on the physical server (hyper-v host).

Here is an excellent reference for Windows Server 2012 licensing.  http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/10/29/windows-server-and-processor-cores-part-2-windows-server-2012.aspx

Comment: This doesn't answer my question of HOW or the best way to activate a guest.

Comment: You use the product key given to you with your license and activate the Windows server vm the same way as a physical server.

Comment: You activate the Windows server VM the same way as physical Windows computers. With your license you're given a product key. If OEM use the product key given to you from Dell, HP, etc. if it is a volume license, you can get the product key at the Microsoft volume licensing center.

Answer (score 0):

Use a KMS if you have sufficient number of OS's (physical or virtual) to activate.  You need 2012 R2 to use AVMA.

Answer (score 0):

The answer sadly is correct (the one you link in technet). While there is a pass through activation, it only is in datacenter (which will auto activate VM's of the right kind while they run on it).

You will have to use up you MAK on the VM's - and then ask MS for more activations in accordance with your license.